# ZipException when running maven build

Tags: java, maven, junit

While running mvn clean install I got the following Exception and mvn process resulted in failure.

Exception:-

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] AbcTest.java:[1,1] cannot access com.company.abc
 ZipException opening "junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar": invalid block type
```

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt jar file. Clear caches and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the exception, we can see it is failing on library `junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar` .

Hence we can conclude that there is some problem with downloaded library jar which would be available in the maven repository.
So we need to delete the contents of the folder at

`<m2 repo location>/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine`
Then re run the build